# how is the voip network working when server is outside nat and clients are inside nat?

Tags: voip, asterisk, sip, asterisknow

I want to install an asterisk on a server with a public ip. The sip clients are behind different NATs. How is the signaling and the rtp packets (the voice) working in this case? Will rtp be peer to peer? Do I need besides asterisk a proxy server? I am new to asterisk and it s configuration file.

I know I want a public ip for server. private ip for clients and the communication between client A and client B needs to be peer to peer.

I am working with asteriskwin32 (the windows version for asterisk)

Comment: The sip clients are on different NATs? Hunh. Never tried that before. Well, the only way they're going to talk to each other is through the common router. They're not going to be able to peer-to-peer directly between each other, if they're on different networks (unless you put a bridge or something between those two networks). If I think of something I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need besides asterisk a proxy server?

Yes. You **must** have and configure all NATed clients to use outbound proxy. Full chain will become `C <-> P <-> S <-> P <-> C`